# Edit action that creates and saves new object instead of updating existing - how to display errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app I have a Course model. For several reasons edit action should not update existing course, but create and save a new one.

Currently in my CoursesController I have following methods doing it:

```
def edit
  find_course
end

def update
  @course = Course.new(permitted_params)
  if @course.save
    redirect_to courses_path, notice: 'Course was updated'
  else
    find_course
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def find_course
  @course = Courses.find(params[:id])
end
```

And views:

```
edit.html.erb

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10"><h3> Edit <%= @course.title %> </h3></div>
</div>

<div>
  <%= render 'form', url:  
  course_path(@course) %>
</div>

_form.html.erb

<%= form_for @course, url: url, :html => { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
  <% if @course.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this Course from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @course.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My code does what is expected: when users edits a course, in fact a new course is being created. The problem is that with this approach I cannot display errors if update action fails, what is normal in this approach because in else statement object containing this info is no longer available.

My question is: what is the best, recommended by best practices and experienced developers approach to:

- display errors in my solution?
- how should I change my approach to have it implemented in a better way?

Comment: What if you just remove `find_course` from else branch?

Comment: I've already tried and get 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Courses#update  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses", :id=>#<Course id: nil, title: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]'   - what makes sense: in update action i create a new '@course', but if there are any errors the '@course' is not saved - so there is no '@course.id' or any other :id param.

Comment: Try to remove `url` parameter from form rendering. Do you have link to courses#show somewhere on edit page?

Comment: when i remove url i have no longer issues with validation errors, but - '@course' get not updated if there are now errors. what seems obvious because there is no object that should be updated.